# Delta data in SQL Server 2008 R2 using Partition function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Looking for an idea to collect the delta data (Means the data modified / deleted / added after a certain date) from an existing system. 
Is this attainable by using the Partition function in SQL Server 2008 R2? I am aware that this can be used to archive the existing data into different filegroups.

**Can we create a Partition function which will write the new data (as a trigger) into the new filegroup?**

We do not have proper audit columns (createdate / modifieddate) in most of the tables :(. At this point of time it is not possible to create new columns in the tables as well.

Any help and thoughts will be much appreciated.

Comment: Partitioning has nothing to do with identifying changes or archiving. SQL Server already provides Change Tracking for this, available in all editions. You don't need to add any columns, just enable change tracking at the database and table level. Enteprise edition also supports Change Data Capture.

Comment: CDC is not available in standard edition of SQL 2008 R2. Unfortunately my customer is using standard edition

Comment: I wrote Change Tracking, not CDC. Change Tracking is available even in Express

Comment: I am sorry. I was not aware about this. Thank you very much. I will go through this for more details. By the way the partition method I mentioned is possible by any chance?

Comment: Partitioning has nothing at all to do with change detection. They deal with how data is stored in files only. While you can have eg monthly partitions and a final "future" partition, moving data between them is *expensive*. Essentially you are moving data from one file to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning isn't about archiving or identifying changes. It's used to split large tables.

SQL Server offers [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) in all editions to track the primary keys of changed rows, the change reason and optionally, the modified column values that changed since a specific database version.

This is a cheap process that doesn't require any modifications to the tables. It records the minimal information needed to identify modified rows. To pull changed rows, you use the `CHANGETABLE` function to pull the PKs that changed since the last check and join with the source tables to pull the modified rows, eg:

```
SELECT  
    CT.ProductID, 
    P.Name, P.ListPrice,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT  
FROM  
    SalesLT.Product AS P  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
  CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SalesLT.Product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT  
ON  
  P.ProductID = CT.ProductID
```

The `CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION` returns I, U ,D depending on whether a row was inserted, updated or deleted.

Another alternative is [Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937(v=sql.105).aspx)  which captures the entire record. Before SQL Server 2016 SP1 it was only available in the Enterprise edition. It's also a heavier process, but you don't have to join with the source tables to load unchanged data.

It's worth noting that with SQL Server 2016 SP1 features that used to be available only in the Enterprise edition, like CDC, partitioning, in-memory tables, compression and columnstores, became available even for Express and LocalDB.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? Or is it just trolling?

Comment: I have up voted this answer few days back. I am not able see that now. Is this a technical issue? The answer was very helpful to me.

Comment: @GopakumarN.Kurup no, someone dowvnoted it without explanation afterwards

Comment: This is very bad. At least they could have been provided the explanation.